# Why I am getting different outputs for the same input in machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I  am testing some machine learning code as seen below, however, I get different out puts for the same input,  what could be the reason behind that?

```python
from sklearn import tree

# Horse Power and Seating capacity 
features = [
 [300,2],
 [450,2],
 [200,8],
 [150,9] 
 ]

# change supercar for 1 and minivan for 2
labels = [1,1,2,2] 

# Decision Tree Classifier 
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Find Pattens in Data FIT 
clf.fit(features,labels)

result = (clf.predict([[1,2]]))


result_extp = { }
result_extp[1] = "Super Car"
result_extp[2] = "Min Van"


# print (result)
print(result_extp[result[0]])
result_extp = { }
result_extp[1] = "Super Car"
result_extp[2] = "Mini Van"
```

EDIT:

this is my output , its more of random :

```python
PS D:\projects\ML> python .\mlforsupercars.py answer : [2] Min Van 
PS D:\projects\ML> python .\mlforsupercars.py answer : [2] Min Van 
PS D:\projects\ML> python .\mlforsupercars.py answer : [2] Min Van 
PS D:\projects\ML> python .\mlforsupercars.py answer : [1] Super Car 
PS D:\projects\ML> python .\mlforsupercars.py answer : [2] Min Van
```

Comment: Your question is unclear; please show *exactly* and *explicitly* what are your inputs & outputs the first and second time

Comment: I thought that when you run the code, its self explainable ,

Comment: result = (clf.predict([[1,2]]))

Comment: The code and your intention are very unclear still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce your issue in scikit-learn 0.18.1 (but again, you have not *demonstrated* that it even exists):

```python
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
# '0.18.1'

# Horse Power and Seating capacity 
features = [
 [300,2],
 [450,2],
 [200,8],
 [150,9] 
 ]

# change supercar for 1 and minivan for 2
labels = [1,1,2,2] 

# Decision Tree Classifier 
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(features,labels)

result1 = (clf.predict([[1,2]]))
print(result1)
# [2]

result2 = (clf.predict([[1,2]]))
print(result2)
# [2]

print(result1==result2)
# [ True]
```

No matter how many times I rerun `result2 = (clf.predict([[1,2]]))`, the result is always `[2]` (i.e. a `'Mini Van'`).

**UPDATE** (after clarification of the *exact* question in the edit)

Like many machine learning models, decision trees include a *random* element when fitted; in order to get *fully* reproducible results between different runs that include *fitting* such models, you need to explicitly provide a value for the `random_state` argument in the model definition (check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)).

In your case, you should simply provide an integer (the exact value does not matter) when defining the model, i.e.:

```python
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
```

after which all runs of your script will come up the same.

Irrespectively of this, a good idea would be to test you model with some input that somewhat *resembles* the value range of the original features; here, your `features[0]` is in the range of 150-450, while you test it with a value of 1. If you had used a more realistic input (say, something like `[180, 7]` instead of `[1, 2]`), there is a good chance that your predictions would be the same even if you have not set explicitly the `random_state` (haven't tested it, though, and it may not work here due to your very small training set, which may easily lead to great variance).